# What's the syntax for hard-coding a boolean value in lightning-input-field tag/component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using a lightning-record-edit-form to update values on an Account record. These values should be hardcoded and are not dynamic. As you see, I have two fields. One is a picklist and the other one is a boolean/checkbox. The picklist is updating fine but I am having problem with the syntax for hardcoding the value of the checkbox field. I've tried numerous combinations but nothing works. These fields should be hidden from the lightning card, so ignore the class and disabled attributes, they're correct.

Can you please suggest the correct syntax here? I have found an alternative way to do this but I would still like to know the correct syntax.

`<lightning-input-field class="slds-hide" field-name="Acc_Status__c" value="Retired" disabled="true">`

`<lightning-input-field class="slds-hide" field-name="PI_Software_Access__c" type="checkbox" checked="true" disabled="true">`

Comment: Use the `value` attribute for all datatypes, `checked` is a property of `lightning-input-field`.

Answer (score 0):

according to the Salesforce's specification, lightning-input-field does not have a `checked` attribute.
I'd try to set the `value` attribute to `true` instead, I guess it should work.

> `value     global          The field value, which overrides the existing value.`

@see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/specification